# Poll's choices are not showing while accessing from view in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am building a Poll App and I am stuck on an Problem.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to access `all three choices of poll` from `view` in `template` BUT only one choices is showing. BUT when i access `Poll` object in view and access choice model from template then all three choices are successfully showing.

models.py

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail_poll', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

forms.py

```
class PollAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    choice1 = forms.CharField(label='Choice 1',max_length=100,min_length=2)
    choice2 = forms.CharField(label='Choice 2',max_length=100,min_length=2)
    choice3 = forms.CharField(label='Choice 3',max_length=100,min_length=2)

    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ['title','choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3']
```

I am increasing choices from `forms`.

views.py

```
def detail_poll(request,poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, id=poll_id)

    for choice in poll.choice_set.all():
        printChoice = choice.choice_text

    context = {
        'printChoice ':printChoice ,
    }

    return render(request, 'detail_poll.html',context)
```

In view i am accessing all the choice from `choice_text` of the `poll`.
I am accessing three choices for vote with the same (choice_set) method in template.

AND When i create poll then poll is successfully saving with all three choices. When i vote then poll is successfully voting with choices.

BUT when i accessing the choices to calculate percentage from view then choices are not showing.
With the same method of `poll.choice_text.all` in template, it does work but not from view.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only showing one choice because you are sending only one choice to context. i.e the last choice. **Check your view thoroughly.** When the `for-loop` stops, `printChoice` will have the last choice and you are sending that to context. So only one choice will be shown in template.

You should iterate over the choices and **save them to a data structure like a `dict`, `set`,  `list` etc, and then send it to the context.**

It should be like this. I have used a list to store the choice_texts and pass it to `context`.

```
def detail_poll(request,poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, id=poll_id)
    choice_set = []
    for choice in poll.choice_set.all():
        choice_set.append(choice.choice_text)
     
   # You can use your percentage calculation here...

    context = {
        'printChoice ': choice_set ,
    }

    return render(request, 'detail_poll.html',context)
```

**You can also send the entire queryset to `context` like this.**

```
context = { 'printChoice': poll.choice_set.all() }
```

And then in `template`, show the `choice_text` like this

```
{% for choice in printChoice %} 
  <p>choice.choice_text</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much, BUT How can i access all the choices differently ? Because i will have to calculate from first choice then second choice then third choice

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you give an example ?

Comment: I mean, I will get percentage of every field. *For example :-*  `choice1 votes / total votes * 100` . `choice2 votes / total votes * 100`. I will voting percentage on every field

Comment: How can i access each choice in view ?  Like `choice.choice1`, `choice.choice2` .